# Mix text and calculated values in table header

Tags: evaluation, list-manipulation, text, output-formatting

I have a simple table:

```
TableForm[Table[{test}, {m, 1, 5}, {n, 1, 5}], 
   TableHeadings -> {{"m=1\nFactorInteger[m1]", 
  "2\nFactorInteger[m2]", "3\nFactorInteger[m3]", 
         "4\nFactorInteger[m4]", 
  "5\nFactorInteger[m5]"}, {"n=1\nFactorInteger[n1]", 
         "2\nFactorInteger[n2]", "3\nFactorInteger[n3]", 
  "4\nFactorInteger[n4]", 
         "5\nFactorInteger[n5]"}}]
```

However, I want calculated values for each instance of `FactorInteger[#]`... How do I do this? `Evaluation->Evaluate in place` doesn't work, it just creates a blank. And I can't find a way to force `StringForm` to do it.

Suggestions?

Comment: Why not use `Column[{"m=1", FactorInteger[m1]}]` instead?

Comment: Hi both. @Carl, the `Column` trick does what I need. Could you convert it to an answer and I'll tick it?

Comment: It also looks like you might want to learn about `StringTemplate`, in case you haven't already!

Answer (score 2):

I think you will find [`StringTemplate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringTemplate.html) very convenient for this task (especially, the ability to make calculations inside `<* ...*>` delimiters):

```
TableForm[Table[{test}, {m, 1, 5}, {n, 1, 5}], 
 TableHeadings -> 
   {StringTemplate["<* If[#==1,\"m =\", \"\"]*> ``\n <* FactorInteger[#] *>"] /@
     Range[5], 
   StringTemplate["<* If[#==1,\"n =\", \"\"]*> ``\n <* FactorInteger[#] *>"] /@
     Range[5]}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use [`StringRiffle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringRiffle.html):

```
TableForm[Table[{test}, {m, 1, 5}, {n, 1, 5}], 
 TableHeadings -> 
  {StringRiffle[{#, FactorInteger@#}, {If[# == 1, "m = ", ""], "\n", ""}]&/@Range[5], 
  StringRiffle[{#, FactorInteger@#}, { If[# == 1, "n = ", ""], "\n", ""}]&/@Range[5]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I don't like using strings when you can use expressions. That is, I like using something like:

```
Column[{HoldForm[m=1], FactorInteger[20]}]
```

[image]

instead of something like:

```
StringForm["m=1\n`1`", FactorInteger[20]]
```

[image]

The primary reasons I like expressions better are because including typesetting in a string will not work when the string is exported, and it can lead to hard to understand issues, like italicization and font issues.

Also, I don't like using [`StringTemplate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringTemplate). An example of why I don't like [`StringTemplate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringTemplate):

```
StringTemplate["foo `s`"][<|"s" -> x^2|>]
```

"foo Power[x, 2]"

So, my suggestion is to use expressions as your table headings.